# Birthday party (logic task): How many friends will appear in best case?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

> Fred wants celebrate his birthday party with as many friends as
>   possbile (Anne, Bernd, Christine, Dirk, Eva). He knows that:
>
> If Bernd and Anne both appear, then Eva will not appear. And Dirk will
>   not appear, if Bernd and Eva both appear. But Eva will appear, if
>   Christine and Dirk appear. On the other hand, Christine will only
>   appear, if Anne also appears. Anne, however, will only appear, if also
>   Bernd or Christine appear.
>
> How many of Fred's friends (and which) will appear at his party in
>   best case?

Sorry for my English, I had to translate everything :p

It's a bit head-aching to read but it might work well if you use variables instead of names and logic operators instead of words.

Let

$$A=\text{Anne appears}\hspace{1cm} B =\text{Bernd appears}\hspace{1cm} C=\text{Christine appears}\hspace{1cm} D =\text{Dirk appears} \hspace{1cm}E = \text{Eva appears}$$

"If Bernd and Anne both appear, then Eva will not appear." $: (B \wedge A) \rightarrow \neg E$

"And Dirk will not appear, if Bernd and Eva both appear." : $(B \wedge E) \rightarrow \neg D$

"But Eva will appear, if Christine and Dirk appear." $(C \wedge D) \rightarrow E$

"On the other hand, Christine will only appear, if Anne also appears." : $A \rightarrow C$

"Anne, however, will only appear, if also Bernd or Christine appear." : $(B \vee C) \rightarrow A$

I might be wrong with the direction of the arrows. But how can I be sure in which direction it goes?

So in the end, those formulas make it much shorter but I cannot quickly say how many people will appear in best case using these formulas. Anything I did wrong till here? And how do you solve this correctly?

Comment: To find the best case. You can construct a truth table for the conjunction of all those statements. The assignment in which most friends come( are assigned as 1 in truth table) and  that satisfy this formula is the best case.

Comment: What kind of drama is this? Hahaha!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last two translations are not correct.  The next to last should be $C\rightarrow A$ and the last should be $A \rightarrow (B \vee C)$.  Now it should be clear that you can have all of $A,C,D,E$ and can't have all five.

Comment: I agree with your solution, but could you say a little more about how it is 'clear'?

Comment: I just looked at the expressions and saw $B$ was a problem, so checked that my set satisfied them all. Then all five fails the first. I haven't shown that this is the only group of four that could come, just that four is the maximum.

Comment: Thanks! I now understand how you know how many people will appear in best case. But how do you know that my last two translations are not correct? I was sure I did a mistake somewhere with the arrows but I don't know how to do it correctly :s

Comment: @RossMillikan "Anne will only appear if Bernd or Christine appear". Why did you use an implication here and not a biconditional ?

Comment: @asddf:  because as I read it it would be acceptable for B or C to appear without A.  " P only if Q" in English generally translates to $P \rightarrow Q$ while "P if Q" translates to $Q \rightarrow P$  To get a biconditional you need if and only if or some equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

'P only if Q' translates to $P \rightarrow Q$